# How do I make the value of an XElement be wrapped in ![CDATA[***]]?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

This is when using XDocument from .net.

I thought this might work...

```
xElement.Element(elementName).Value = new XCData(value).ToString();
```

... but it comes out like this...

```
<name>&lt;![CDATA[hello world]]&gt;</name>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try

```
xElement.Element(elementName).ReplaceNodes(new XCData(value));
```

Comment: Thanks :) and just to add for me I needed the CDATA to replace another element which had more sibling nodes so used ReplaceWith but the idea came from your answer.

Answer (score 49):

[XCData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcdata.aspx) is a type of [XNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.aspx). As such, you should try to [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354061.aspx) it to the element, rather than set the value (which is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx) to be the flattened text content of the element):

```
xElement.Element(elementName).Add(new XCData(value));
```

Answer (score 46):

If you are creating the [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) (vs. modifying it), you can also just add add it directly in the constructor as the content like so:

```
new XElement(elementName, new XCData(value));
```